# Is it possible to substitute log file name from environment/system properties is OrientDB?

Tags: java, logging, orientdb

OrientDB handles logs using the Java Logging Framework.Logging is configured using `orientdb-server-log.properties`.

output file path is specified as

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=../log/orient-server.log
```

Is it possible to substitute value of `java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern` from environment/system properties?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you run an embedded server in your jvm ( e.g: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Embedded-Server.html ), and you start java process with  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=$ORIENTDB_HOME/config/orientdb-server-log.properties , you can use

```
String pattern = LogManager.getLogManager().
                 getProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern" );
System.out.println("java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern  : "+pattern);
```

to get:

```
2017-01-27 16:34:28:291 INFO  OrientDB Server is active v2.2.15. [OServer]
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern  : ../log/orient-server.log
```

2) In script server.sh there is

```
ORIENTDB_LOG_CONF=$ORIENTDB_HOME/config/orientdb-server-log.properties
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="$ORIENTDB_LOG_CONF"
```

so you can grep value

```
ORIENTDB_LOG_FILEHANDLER=$( printf "%s" \`grep "java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern" $ORIENTDB_LOG_CONF | cut -f2 -d'=' | tr -d '\r'\` )".0"
```

to extract file handler pattern "../log/orient-server.log.0"

3) If using Oracle JDK to run orientdb server you can use jps to get pid, then jinfo pid. e.g:

```
$ jps -l | grep OServer
74481 com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain
$ jinfo -sysprops 74481 | grep java.util.logging.config.file
java.util.logging.config.file = /mypath/orientdb-enterprise-2.2.15/config/orientdb-server-log.properties
```

Or use the new tool jcmd with main class and available command for the process. e.g:

```
$ jcmd com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain help
...
VM.system_properties
...
$ jcmd com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain VM.system_properties | grep java.util.logging.config.file
java.util.logging.config.file=/mypath/orientdb-enterprise-2.2.15/config/orientdb-server-log.properties
```

Then you can grep properties file to extract file handler pattern

Comment: Thanks for detailed response, but I think my questing was confusing actually which i have corrected. I wanted to substitute Environment/System variable  for value of `java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern` property